# How to filter array of data with by category?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Here is my `vue` page on Nuxt js:

```
<template> 
  <div>
   <select
    id="category"
    name="category"
    v-model="selected">
     <option value="0">categories</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
   <services-list :list="services.list" /> 
 </div>
<template>

export default {
  components: {
    ServicesList
  },
  data() {
    return {
      services: {
        list: [
          {
            name: 'NAME1',
            title: 'TITLE1',
            category: '1'
          },
          {
            name: 'NAME2',
            title: 'TITLE2',
            category: '2'
          },
         }
        }
       }
```

I need to filter rendered data based on a selected category from `<select>`.
I tried changing the state on change of `<select>` but it works only first time. because the data in state would change and running it the second time will not give the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the filtered `list` from `selected`, use a `computed`

```js
computed{
  filtered(){
    if (this.selected === null) return this.services.list
    return this.services.list.filter(s => s.category === this.selected)
  }
}
```

Then you can use `filtered` in your template

Comment: I can't access v-model (this.selected) in computed , why ?

Comment: I mean this.selected is always undefined in filtered()

Comment: @hesamsameni poorly formatted answer. Remove the duplicate `return` statement.

Comment: I figured it out , this answers return true or false , I want the whole object so I replace .map() with .filter()

Answer (score 1):

```
  computed: {
    filtered() {
      if (this.selected === null) return this.services.list
      return this.services.list.filter(obj => obj.category === this.selected)
    }
  }
```